# Arrays of objects in Backbone Form

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-forms

I am using backbone forms for my current project and I am finding difficulties with creating the schema for Arrays,

```
 schema:{
        name:{},
        description:{},
        partition:{},
        'addresses':[{type:'Object',subSchema:{address:{}, description:{}}}]


    }
```

this is my schema

```
 var obj = {
                name:'suchita',
                description:'device3 desc',
                partition:'346',
                'addresses':
                    [{address:'abc', description:'xyz'}]

            };

           var user=new Model(obj);
```

and this is where I fill the schema. Now my api wants me to send an array of "addresses" object i.e

addresses:
     0: {address:'abc',description:'xyz'}
     1: {address:'uio',description:'uiyui'}

but somehow it doesn't happen in this way. Can you help me in where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late but I think the syntax with a list is something like:

```
schema:{
    name:{},
    description:{},
    partition:{},
    addresses: {type:'List',itemType: 'Object', 
        subSchema:{
            address:{}, 
            description:{}
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you have to include the List editor for backbone-forms:

```
<script src="backbone-forms/distribution/editors/list.min.js"></script>
```

And you can fill in with:

```
var obj = { addresses: [
    {
        address: 'my address', 
        description: 'home'
    }
]};

var user = new Model(obj);
```

I haven't checked if this works but I have a similar case in my code so it should work

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the types of your schema fields, something like:

```
schema:{
    name: {type:'Text'},
    description: {type:'TextArea'},
    partition: {type:'Text'},
    addresses:[{type:'Object', subSchema:{
                  address:{type:'Text'}, 
                  description:{type:'TextArea'}
              }}]
}
```